# numbers and text in same field

Tags: javascript, calculator

I can't get the numbers and text in same form field to force two decimal places or do Total figure.

[This is the link](http://www.naturalfloorcoverings.com.au/_TEST_calculator-1.htm).

I am trying to get the last 3 cells to work with two decimal places.
e.g. Total sq mt figure x Price should calculate the Cost cell.

Also want to get the Cost cell (NaN) working !
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, you need to clarify better what are you trying to do and what is not working

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please post your code.

Comment: The font element has been deprecated since 1999 - use styles for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to do something like this

```
function calc(val1, val2) { // this is NOT a replacement for your Calculate function
    val1 = parseFloat(val1.replace(/[^\d\.-]/g, ''));
    val2 = parseFloat(val2.replace(/[^\d\.-]/g, ''));
    return (val1 * val2).toFixed(2);
}
```

NOTE: the above returns a **STRING**

and STOP redefining with `Math.round` in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Math.round(num * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

Should format your number with two decimal places.